# Looking for a verb describing a person who's put his hand on his ear so as not to hear others' voice

Tags: word-request

Well, this time this question is quite hard for me to ask. The title is rather self-explanatory, and I just bring an example up.

> Why do you always **[...]** (your ear) when someone tells you the truth?

- I'm looking for a verb instead of the phrase "put your hands on"

You may find this picture handy (though I mean someone puts both hands on his ears):

[image]

Comment: The first word came to my mind: *cover*.

Comment: I agree with @DamkerngT. Another option might be _blocking_: The girl is [_blocking_](https://www.google.com/search?q=blocking+her+ears&biw=1742&bih=978&tbm=isch) her ears.

Comment: The verb is: Lalalalalalalalalala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly. Damkerng nails it.

I often use the phrase while speaking to my daughter sarcastically... *`cover your ears, I'm gonna tell you the bitter truth!'*.

We generally use 'covering our senses' so as to avoid having the perceptions they are meant for.

> Why do you cover your ears (with your hands) when someone tells you the truth?

Worth to note that even if you say, 'cover your ears' it *includes* covering with hands!

MM has an entry

> [cover *(#1b)*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cover) - to put your hands over your eyes, ears ... etc.